# Why Spark-BigQuery creates extra tables in the dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-bigquery-connector

So i am running a spark (scala) serverless dataproc job that reads and write data from/in bigquery.

Here is the code that writes the data :

```
df.write.format("bigquery").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("table", "table_name").save()
```

Everythings works fine but these extra tables got created on my dataset in addition of the final table. Do you know why and what i can do so i wont have them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those tables are created as the result of view materialization or loading result from a query. The have an expiry time of 24 hours, configurable by the materializationExpirationTimeInMinutes option

Comment: Thank you David. So this is a normal behaviour when writing in/overwriting  a table in bigquery right? I had no clue maybe because i usually create a table then load it with data. I guess i will configure the materializationExpirationTimeInMinutes. I wish there is an option not to have them.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal behavior.